# How to resolve (OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on my Facebook fan page using Facebook Graph API. To do this I am using extended Page access token. I was able to post my contents on Facebook, but the moment I logged out from administrator account and tried posting the contents on my Fan Page I am getting this error. Please guide me how can I resolve this issue?

**To get Extended Page Access token I have followed these processes-**

1. Created an FB App to get AppID and AppSecret.
2. Headed over to Facebook Graph API Explorer
3. On the top right in "Application" I have selected my app which I have created.
4. Clicked on Get Access Token Button
5. Added "manage_pages" permission.
6. Converted short-lived access token into a long lived one by making this Graph API
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MYID&client_secret=MYSECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=SHORT LIVED TOKEN
7. Grabbed new long lived access token returned back.
   Now I am using this long lived access token in my code. Please guide me how can I resolve this issue.

**CS Code-**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckAuthorization();
    }

    private void CheckAuthorization()
    {
        string app_id = "XXXXXX";
        string app_secret = "XXXXX";
        //string my_url = "http://localhost:6943/ashish/Default2.aspx";
        string scope = "publish_stream, publish_actions, manage_pages, email,user_location,user_birthday";
        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
            {
                tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                    token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
            }
            string access_token = "Long Lived Access Token";
var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            parameters.link = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
            parameters.picture = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            parameters.name = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            parameters.caption = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
client.Post("/FB Fan page ID/feed", parameters);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When receiving this error, you should re-initialise the authentication process. This is due to security reasons; when logging out, all associated access tokens (can be) reset.

You can not solve this issue without interaction from the administrator. So the way to handle this is catching this situation and directing the user to the authentication part in your app.